# Manual input while running phantomjs casperjs

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

Is it possible to make the script (phantomjs or casperjs) to stop for **manual human input** (keyboard typing) before going to the next step?

For example, the script will fill out a form and export the whole screen as .png then wait for user input to fill in the last field before click submit. Captcha is one of the barrier required this. I don't want to deal with Captcha breaker / solver or anything like that since it's only one time thing per run.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never done it, but, I know the script you write that gets executed in the browser/phantom, can send an ajax request to some local webserver. There's your external communication.

```
->screenshot 
->send to local server
->someones open web browser polls the server for new data entry jobs
->human submits one
->server receives submission
->server routes the response back to that initial ajax request
->that ajax request that got sent from phantomjs finally receives a response.
```

This workflow can be done using any kind of external communication possible from phantom/casper(I'm just not familiar with them). I'm sure ajax works, so i used it as an example.

Comment: My workaround now is to use FileSystem and read a file content for captcha string. But I try to find out if there is better way to do this. Ajax seems overkill to me.

Comment: hey @HP. I'm in the same situation as you. Can you please provide me with more info on your workaround with FileSystem?Did you find a better way to implement this? Thank you

Comment: Using FS is a very ugly hack. I would not recommend. Basically I use some kind of timer `setTimeout` to wait for a bit before reading a file. So within that 20 seconds or so, I quickly edit the text file to provide the input.